# Designing a rich UI using Webview for a non-network-using Android application

Tags: java, html, android, css, webview

I am in the process of designing an application for android where the user can see a list of resources with short summary (e.g., title and date of an event) , and clicking on an item shows the details (e.g., event description, who is attending, etc). Currently I am exploring making a custom `ListView` and `LinearLayout` for this in Android, but styling elements looks a bit tedious.

I have read/noticed that many apps such as GMail and Twicca use webview for a large part of their UI. Since I have more HTML/CSS experience than I have Java UI experience, I am considering going that route.

Hence this set of (related questions)

- How do I enable loading of 'local' pages using URLs in the web view? [e.g., provide a hyperlink for the details page of an event as a url on the list page, which is loaded in the same webview, without accessing the internet]
- Can I refer to a "local" CSS file to style my app?

Thanks in advance for your answers (or links to good resources).
-A
P.S. I searched on this site, but I could only find fragments of this question.

Comment: Thats a lot of really generic questions.  You might get better answers if you ask 1 specific, targeted question and include information about the things you have already tried or researched.

Comment: Thanks. I have edited the question according to your suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to load a local file, try

```
String url = "file:///android_asset/test.html";
webView.loadUrl(url);
```

The test.html file must be stored at the assets folder you may create in your project. I have no problems with CSS, try storing the CSS-Files in a seperate folder at assets.

Hope I could help you, feedback welcome,

jonathan